# String center and bottom in button

Tags: android, button, center, gravity

How do I position a the text of my `Button` to be centered horizontally and at the bottom?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Use the gravity attribute:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
```